# A public action method was not found on controller - HEAD requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver, http-verbs

I'm seeing lots of the following error, which I think is down to HEAD requests to an action method (from bots perhaps):

```
A public action method 'index' was not found on controller     'MyWebsite.MyController'.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at EPiServer.Web.Mvc.ActionControllerBase.HandleUnknownAction(String     actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult     asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at     System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyn    cResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at     System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyn    cResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult     asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at     System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyn    cResult asyncResult)
   at     System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.I    ExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&     completedSynchronously)
```

My action method was originally only set up to accept GET requests, but I have now changed it to accept HEAD requests too e.g.:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Head)]
    public async override Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
      ....
      return View(new Model());
    }
```

However, when I test a HEAD request for the page, I'm seeing the same error in the response and a 404 status code.

Anbody have any ideas what could be causing this please?

**UPDATED** to include Controller inheritance (removed quite a bit for simplicity):

MyController...

```
 public class MyController: BasicContentPageController<MyPageType>
{


    public MyController(IPageUrlProvider pageUrlProvider)
        : base(pageUrlProvider)
    {

    }

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Head)]
    public async override Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
    ...
    return View(new Model());
    }

}
```

...inherits from BasicContentPageController...

```
 public abstract class BasicContentPageController<T> : MyBasePageContoller<T> where T : MyBasePageType
    {

 protected BasicContentPageController(IPageUrlProvider pageUrlProvider)
        : base(pageUrlProvider)
    {

    }

 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Head)]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await GetBasicPageViewModel());
    }

}
```

...inherits from MyBasePageController...

```
 public abstract class MyBasePageContoller<T> : PageController<T>
    where T : MyBasePageType
{
protected readonly IPageUrlProvider PageUrls;

 protected MyBasePageContoller(IPageUrlProvider pageUrlProvider)
    {
        PageUrls = pageUrlProvider;

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the URL that causes the problem?

Comment: How are you testing your HEAD request? In a browser or with a tool such as Fiddler or Postman?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is an example, but it's happening for all controllers. e.g  if I test with the homepage (http://localhost:67829/) and make a HEAD request, I get the error.

Comment: @Horizon_Net  I'm testing in Fiddler.

Comment: What controller class are you inheriting? Perhaps you could post the entire code for one of the failing controllers?

Comment: Which 7.x.xxx version of EPiServer are you using?

Comment: @EricHerlitz using 7.19.2.0

Comment: @TedNyberg  there are several levels of inheritance. This controller inherits from a 'BasicContentPageController' (which defines the Index() method that I'm overriding in MyWebsite.MyController), which in turn inherits from another controller 'MyBasePageContoller', which inherits from EPiServer.Web.MVC.PageController.

Comment: @TedNyberg I've updated the description with more info on how the controllers are defined

Comment: Just a raincheck, shouldn't your Index() have the `currentPage` parameter?